# Should I quote variable when passing to command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I always do this when passing variable to command

```
mkdir -p "$dir_to_make"
```

are those quotes needed? I tried to google but didn't find much. I always write them, just interested if they are necessary.

Comment: They are necessary if the filename has special characters.

Comment: so in general purpose script they are probably good idea?

Comment: @Paladin Absolutely. Quote, unless you have a specific reason not to. Saves you from worrying about word splitting, glob expansions, and the contexts in which they take place.

Comment: Exactly what 123 and PSkocik are saying.  If you do `A="mydir/My Photos"; mkdir -p $A` (i.e. without the quotes on `$A`) you will get three dirs instead of two: `./mydir`, `./mydir/My` and `./Photos`.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells